# Stateful grid in ExtJs 7.3 MODERN

Tags: extjs

I don't get it, according to the manual for ExtJs 7.3 Modern it should be possible to configure a Ext.grid.Grid (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#cfg-stateful).

I've added:

```
({
  //  ...
  stateId: 'state-grid', 
  stateful: true, 
  // ... 
});
```

and on the columns also added an stateId for each column and in the applications launch function I've added:

```
launch: function() {
        Ext.state.Provider.register(new Ext.state.LocalStorage());
        Ext.get(Ext.query('#appLoadingIndicator')).remove();
        this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

But I dont get the stateful grid to work, i.e. I hide a column and then refresh the site.. the column is still visible. So does stateful work at all in ExtJs 7.3 MODERN <--- Modern not classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following self-explainable fiddle sample. It saves the width and hidden properties of the grid column:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.state.Provider.register(new Ext.state.LocalStorage());

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        });

        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                stateId: 'name-column-state-id',
                stateful: {
                    // we will state hidden and width of the column states only
                    hidden: true,
                    width: true
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                stateId: 'email-column-state-id',
                stateful: {
                    // we will state hidden and width of the column states only
                    hidden: true,
                    width: true
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                stateId: 'phone-column-state-id',
                stateful: {
                    // we will state hidden and width of the column states only
                    hidden: true,
                    width: true
                }
            }],
            store: store,
            layout: 'fit',
            fullscreen: true
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly for the hidden state of the column, but it seems like it will not apply the width for the column if I have width as stateful and change it while dragging it. And the column order if I move a column will not either be saved for the grid. 

So it feels like the modern state of the grid is not perfectly there or the documentation is VERY poor for things like moving columns and keep state of it.

Comment: You asked for hidden state of the grid, I have shown how to do it. In the above sample the width stated.. columnmove is a little bit another story..

Comment: Not really just hidden columns, generally speaking grid state, the hidden column was just an example. 

But I has accepted the answer as it got me a bit further in the devlopment.